# How do I testfor/scoreboard a Player in a MinecartRideable (1.9)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am attempting to create a Minecart mechanic where once the player is in the Minecart it starts moving in a certain direction. I am not a beginner with command blocks, so in your answer you can talk technical with me. I am just not familiar with the new 1.9 tags.

I have attempted (on an active 20hz or repeating clock)

I.

```
1. /scoreboard players set @a ridingCart 0
2. /scoreboard players set @a ridingCart 1 {Passengers:[{id:"MinecartRideable"}]}
```

II.

```
1. /scoreboard players set @e[type=MinecartRideable] ridingCart 0
2. /scoreboard players set @e[type=MinecartRideable] ridingCart 1 {Passengers:[{id:"Player"}]}
```

Neither of these two separate attempts have worked. I am unsure if this is a bug with the game to where you cannot /testfor with the Passengers tag or if it is a mistake on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a player is a passenger to an entity, that player is not saved with the entity in the region files (side-note that `Player` is not a valid entity ID and is simply a feature of selector syntax).

The entity is instead saved with the player via the `RootVehicle` compound in player files and is no longer saved within the chunk region files. Example structure within `player.dat`:

```
{
    Sleeping:0b,
    Inventory:[],
    RootVehicle:{
        AttachLeast:1l,
        AttachMost:1l,
        Entity:{
            id:"MinecartRideable"
        }
    }
}
```

To detect when a player is riding anything, you'll check the `RootVehicle` tag:

```
/scoreboard players set @a ridingCart 1 {RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:"MinecartRideable"}}}
```

The entity, when ridden by a player, will **not** have the `Passengers` tag containing the player and will not exist if only the player is riding it. If there are non-player entities riding the same vehicle as the player (such as a pig and player inside a boat), the `Passengers` tag will exist on the boat within `RootVehicle` but will only contain the pig.

If the vehicle has non-player passengers but no player passenger, `Passengers` will exist like normal and the vehicle is stored within region files.

If the vehicle itself is riding another entity (such as a boat riding an armor stand), and the player rides the vehicle, the `AttachLeast` and `AttachMost` will be the UUID of the vehicle the player is riding (the boat) while `Entity` starts with the bottom-most entity (the armor stand), complete with `Passengers` containing the boat.

Note that thus far into 1.9 (15w47c), `RootVehicle` is only available on players, meaning you cannot detect what a non-player entity is a passenger of.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Also, you said that if you and a pig are in a boat the boat will only have the Pig in the Passengers tag. What would happen if you changed the data of the boat while you were riding in it to contain two entities?

Comment: @creeperpig28 That would involve instantiating new entities, while `/entitydata` can only modify data. `/summon` has a special case to instantiate new entities if the `Passengers` (previously `Riding`) tag was defined; that would have to be extended to `/entitydata`, although there is the other issue of specifying a list-type tag which overwrites all pre-existing data within the list prior. And while you can modify the `Passengers` tag with `/entitydata`, any changes you make won't matter since the real passengers are determined on chunk loading, not from NBT merging.

Comment: @Skylinerw if the `Passengers` tag is inside the `RootVehicle` Tag which a tag of the player's, `entitydata` shouldn't be able to do anything since it can't act on players in the first place.

Comment: @MrLemon Target selectors will target the instantiated entity. You can still target the vehicle while the player is riding it to change its data, just not through the player (that is, by targeting the boat or minecart directly, not the player's `RootVehicle` data).